# Where do I download an RPM from?

Tags: rpm, software-installation

Where do I download a source RPM from?

Comment: From your distribution provider? If you want more a specific answer, you'll have to give more information.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given much information, so the easiest thing to say is:

Run `rpm -qi <package name> | grep Source` and then Google for that file name.

In general, what you should try is to find a download mirror for your distribution.  For example, the Fedora 14 mirror list is at [mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/Fedora/14/i386/](http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/Fedora/14/i386/).

Then navigate to find the SRPMs folder for the release you have, e.g. something like [/fedora/linux/releases/14/Fedora/source/](http://mirror.optus.net/fedora/linux/releases/14/Fedora/source/).

Other useful resources:

- [rpm.pbone.net](http://rpm.pbone.net)
- [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net)
- [DAG](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/)
- [rpmforge spec files](http://svn.rpmforge.net/viewvc/rpmforge/trunk/rpms/)
- [RPMforge@apt.sw.be](http://apt.sw.be/)

Answer (score 0):

Usually most rpm-based distributions make the SRPMs available on their mirrors in the SRPMS directory. Using that you can manually download the src.rpm package from the HTTP or FTP server. Also, there is another way, using yumdownloader as described [here](http://www.imminentweb.com/technologies/yum-download-source-rpm).

Personally, more often I get srpms manually, but, depending on what do you want to do, your mileage may vary.